# Regular expression that match decimal places

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code to test if a value entered in a `INPUT` is numeric:

```
$("#price").val().match(/^\d+$/);
```

I need some help rewriting this function to allow decimal places either with **colon** or **dot** meaning for example `230.00` is allowed and `230,00` is allowed too. Also the decimal places could be four or less. Any?

Comment: @TusharGupta comma sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex: `$("#price").val().match(/^\d+([,\.]\d{1,4})?$/);`

Regex n2 with negative values: `$("#price").val().match(/^-?\d+([,\.]\d{1,4})?$/);`

If you need help parsing values related to some culture in specific, take a loot at this https://github.com/jquery/globalize. It's a library about globalization and localization.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This did the job perfectly

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#price").val().match(/^\d+((\.|,)\d+)?$/);
```

the above won't limit the number of decimal places to four, though.

By the way, that's a **comma** and not a "colon"

To match decimal places up to 4 only, use this

```
$("#price").val().match(/^\d+((\.|,)\d{1,4})?$/);
```

should match 1 to four numbers after . or ,